# location of exception in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a project with both a winForm project and a class library project.  The winform project obviously depends on the class library.

The winform counts on a widget class from the class library.  However, the widget class throws an exception with one of its methods.  What is frustrating is that VS is breaking on the line in the winForm app that calls the widget's method, NOT in the Widget class itself.  It used to! This makes it way harder to debug. I'm wondering if there is a setting somewhere that got messed up to not break INTO referenced libraries?

Example:

WinApp:

```
Widget myWidget = new Widget();
myWidget.DeleteFiles();
```

In the widget class:

```
public void DeleteFiles()
{
   foreach (FileInfo currFile in ThisWidgetsFileCollection)
   {  File.Delete(currFile.FullName);}
}
```

When the widget can't delete the file (due to access restrictions), the debugger breaks to the line

```
myWidget.DeleteFiles();
```

NOT

```
{currFile.Delete();}
```

Hopefully that makes sense?  Thoughts?

Comment: Oops, I think that was supposed to be {File.Delete(currFile.FullName);}  but hopefully you get the idea!

Comment: The debugger will show the source code when it can.  You've done something to prevent it from seeing the source code.  Like building and referencing the Release version of the class library.  Or not having the PDB file.  Start by having both projects in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration manager in Visual Studio, make sure that both projects are set to DEBUG. Then right-click your solution and choose Clean Solution. Also make sure the reference from your Winforms project to the library is a Project reference (not referencing some DLL directly).

Then Debug your application and it should work properly.